# Detect immediate parent rows of each row and add their values to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, hierarchical-data

I have a dataframe that contains multiple hierarchy columns and a value attach to them, something like this:

|  | location hierarhcy | industry hierarchy | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | US | All | V1 |
| 1 | US-California | All | V2 |
| 2 | US-California | All-HT | V3 |
| 3 | US-California-LA | All | V4 |
| 4 | US-California-LA | All-HT | V5 |
| 5 | US-California-LA | All-HT-SoftWare | V6 |
| 6 | US-California-LA | All-Manufacturing | V7 |

Now I want to find the **immediate** parents of each row and add their value a a new column. My example just shows two parents but it could be more. So, the expected output would be as follows:

|  | location hierarhcy | industry hierarchy | value | value-parent-1 | value-parent-2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | US | All | V1 | **NA** | **NA** |
| 1 | US-California | All | V2 | **V1** | **NA** |
| 2 | US-California | All-HT | V3 | **V2** | **NA** |
| 3 | US-California-LA | All | V4 | **V2** | **NA** |
| 4 | US-California-LA | All-HT | V5 | **V3** | **V4** |
| 5 | US-California-LA | All-HT-SoftWare | V6 | **V5** | **NA** |
| 6 | US-California-LA | All-Manufacturing | V7 | **V4** | **NA** |

My Dataframe could be extremely large, so the speed and memory are important factors. So, row-wise process won't really work.

**Logic**:

The immediate parents for a row will be all rows that are one level higher than one of the hierarchies. For example for row 5, the potential immediate parents will be:

| - | location hierarhcy | industry hierarchy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | US-California | All-HT-SoftWare |
| 1 | US-California-LA | All-HT |

This is the code to create the dataframe if you want to play with it.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'location hierarchy': ['US', 'US-California', 'US-California', 'US-California-LA', 'US-California-LA', 'US-California-LA', 'US-California-LA'],
                   'industry hierarchy': ['All', 'All', 'All-HT', 'All', 'All-HT', 'All-HT-SoftWare', 'All-Manufacturing'],
                   'value': ['V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5', 'V6', 'V7']})
```

Comment: What is the explicit logic of the hierarchy?

Comment: Also, running your code doesn't give the provided output (it gives `[0, 'V1', 'V1', 'V2', 'V2', 'V2', 'V2']`)

Comment: @mozway you are right, I removed the code and also fix the last code block to represent what I put in the table. Can you clarify your question please: "What is the explicit logic of the hierarchy?"

Comment: Well, explain in words why you get the values in the output. Why is V3 the parent of V5? Why is there only V4 in the second column? I don't see a clear logic

Comment: @mozway oh, "All" is the root of industry hierarchy. I changed the values in the column to reflect it.

Comment: Sorry, but still highly unclear, there are many different interpretations, you **must** break down the logic clearly with examples.

Comment: NB. I get that "All" is the root, this is fine, the rest is unclear (how the mapping is done, given the provided output). For instance, if you consider US-California-LA/All-Manufacturing, shouldn't the parent be US-California/All, i.e. V2? But you show V4 in the output. Anyway, busy on other things, I'll check back eventually to see if the question is clarified.

Comment: @mozway I added the logic in the question. Hope it makes it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Location Hierarchy': ['US', 'US-California', 'US-California', 'US-California-LA', 'US-California-LA', 'US-California-LA', 'US-California-LA'],
                   'Industry Hierarchy': ['All', 'All', 'All-HT', 'All', 'All-HT', 'All-HT-SoftWare', 'All-Manufacturing'],
                   'Value': ['V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5', 'V6', 'V7']})

hierarchies = ["Location Hierarchy", "Industry Hierarchy"]
for i, hierarchy in enumerate(hierarchies): 
    df1 = df.copy()
    df1[hierarchy] = df1[hierarchy].str.split('-').str[:-1].str.join("-")
    df[f"Value_parent_{i+1}"] = df1.merge(df, on=hierarchies, how="left", suffixes=["", "_parent"])["Value_parent"]
```